# How to override default unique boundary string and create our own boundary using MimeMultipart of JavaMail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types, mime-message

I have a web-app which I use which expects a specific boundary string like (“company mime boundary”).

I did not find a way to override the default behavior of MimeMultipart,  when I do

`Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();`

A unique boundary string is always created by the constructor and I want to override this behavior to have my own boundary string, but unable to do so as I did not find any API.

Even if I set it in content-type, it does not work and creates a unique boundary string always as the MimeMultipart is creating a default one.

`mimeMsg.setHeader("Content-Type","multipart/mixed;boundary="company mime boundary");`

Can anyone please suggest/help me on this.

How to override this default behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [javax.mail.Multipart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) :

> The `mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter` System property may be set to true to cause any boundary to be ignored and instead search for a boundary line in the message

Try setting this property to `true` and then add your own using

```
mimeMsg.setHeader("Content-Type","");
```

I have not implemented it, but I am confident it can work

**update**

Try sub-classing the MimeMultipart class and overwrite the `getBoundaryMethod()`. See some sample code below:

```
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.ContentType;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
public class MyMimeMultyPart extends MimeMultipart {
    /**
     * DataSource that provides our InputStream.
     */
    protected DataSource ds;

    /**
     * Indicates if the data has been parsed.
     */
    protected boolean parsed = true;

    private ContentType type;

    public MyMimeMultyPart(DataSource dataSource) throws MessagingException {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    public MyMimeMultyPart(String subtype) {
        type = new ContentType("multipart", subtype, null);
        type.setParameter("boundary", getBoundary());
        contentType = type.toString();
    }

    public MyMimeMultyPart() {
        super();
    }

    private static int part;

    private synchronized static String getBoundary() {
        int i;
        synchronized (MimeMultipart.class) {
            i = part++;
        }
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(64);
        buf.append("----=_Part_").append(i).append('_').append((new Object()).hashCode()).append('.').append(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, i still see 
`------=_Part_1_89627259.1352127376871` gets added even after setting that property :(

Comment: Should we not add boundary in the same line like this?
`Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="company mime boundary" `

Comment: Hm, reading some more about it I think it should be better to try and subclass the MimeMultipart class. See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081739/altering-a-multipart-xxx-content-type-without-altering-the-underlying-parts . It might help you

Comment: Perfect @MaVRoSCy !!
Can't thank you enough !!, only override of the method works.